# How to configure NLog file-based logging in app.config file

Tags: ignite

Can we configure NLog file-based logging in app.config file ? Following link 
https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/logging  has an programed way of doing it in c#, but no example of completely configuring it in app.config file!

Answer (score 3):

There's a tab named "app.config" there in the [docs section](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/logging#section-nlog-log4net-loggers) that shows the following example:

```
<igniteConfiguration>
  <logger type="Apache.Ignite.NLog.IgniteNLogLogger, Apache.Ignite.NLog" />
</igniteConfiguration>
```

Comment: I am looking for file based loggingg ! Is that enough for file-based logging ?

Comment: @MaheshTalreja if you have additional questions please file them with "Ask Question" button.